# How do I load Java Access Bridge class into the JVM programmatically?

Tags: java, java-access-bridge

I want to enable the Java Access Bridge at run time.

So creating the Java agent for the same which will inject in the selected JVM.
But I want to the load Java Access Bridge into JVM, in a running Java application.